# Declaring a field without a default constructor

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to C++, and sorry if this is a trivial question. I used the search function to no avail.

Let us assume I have the following class, and let us keep in mind that `BattleObject` has no default constructor.

```
class HostView{       
    public:
        void Update();
    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Currently selected enemy target
        /// </summary>
        BattleObject _selected_enemy_target;
}
```

I know that members have to be initialized when instantiating a class, but since `BattleObject` has no default constructor, is the only solution to use it as a pointer?

```
BattleObject* _selected_enemy_target
```

So that I initialize it only when the user selects a target? Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: Reading some documentation might help you. I'd start here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: I am sorry I know what initializer lists are but how can I apply initializer list to this problem, I am at a loss. I would really appreciate some feedback

Comment: Given what you described-- the need for a member that cannot be initialized at construction, a pointer member is probably correct. That said, you should probably use a C++-style pointer rather than a c-style pointer. More information here: https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers

Comment: @Dr.Watson, Thank you very much I was considering smart_pointers as well. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class can initialize its member variables by specifying an initializer list in the constructor:

```
HostView::HostView()
    : _selected_enemy_target(custom, constructor, arguments)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should mention that elements needed to create an enemy target are available only after any user joins the battle. So at the time of creation of host we simply do not have any parameter to create any enemy

Comment: @EmrahSüngü That sounds like you shouldn't have a `BattleObject` instance at the beginning, then. A pointer (or smart pointer) would be a good alternative, particularly if you just want to refer to an existing object elsewhere (instead of creating a copy).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. As I mentioned in the question, are you suggessting to declare the private field as`BattleObject* _selected_enemy_target;` so that I initialize it only when user selects a target and of course enough information is available?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü Yes. You should also initialize it in the constructor (`HostView() : _selected_enemy_target(nullptr) { ... }`) so you can check whether you have a selected target.

Answer (score 2):

You should use something called an *initializer list*. Let's assume that the constructor of `BattleObject` receives a boolean and a string as argument, then the implementation of `HostView` should be something like this:

```
class HostView{

    public:
        void Update();
        HostView() : _selected_enemy_target(true, "I'm the enemy")
        {
            // initialise your HostView object as usual
        }
    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Currently selected enemy target
        /// </summary>
        BattleObject _selected_enemy_target;
 }
```

Extra tip: keep the order of the objects in the initialiser list the same order as they are declared in the class body.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should mention that elements needed to create an enemy target are available only after any user joins the battle. So at the time of creation of host we simply do not have any parameter to create any enemy

Comment: So ou have the following options: allow `BattleObject ` receives its arguments after its creation (via set functions) or store the BattleObject on a pointer and instantiate when the connection is ready.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I usually want my constructors to completely make the object into a usable state. I considered giving parameters after they are available but I am coming from a C#, Java background and having functions similar to `Initialize` is usually bad design indicator. I ma not sure about c++ though

Comment: An `Initialize` wasn't the idea I was suggesting. I was suggesting just having the object in a default - but valid - state until you have the full information so you could change its state by calling some modifier function (e.g. `setPosX()`)